# Save my all SF Cert. as my dev account (connected to webassessor) login lost due to SF Authenticator?

Tags: community, trailhead, login-errors, webassessor

I am concerned I will lose my all Salesforce Certifications.

Actually, I have a Developer org with my personal email for which I had configured Salesforce Authenticator based two-way authentication. Last week I lost my old phone. Now, I'm not able to login into that personal developer org which is Connected to WebAssessor account and to trailhead account.

I have sent a couple of emails to "trailhead@salesforce.com" but didn't get any reply.

As 23 Aug is the due date for various certifications maintenance, If I won't be able to login into there then I'll lose my Salesforce credentials which need to be maintained by 23 Aug.

Any single suggestion to get this problem resolved will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you completely lost access to account, you cannot really do anything from your side.
I was in a similar situation about a year back. You will get help by sending mail to `certification@salesforce.com`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/114274)

Comment: am confused by your flag @Reshma. It actually is answer, not clarification request.

Comment: @salesforcesas it got marked as low quality due to short length. No worries, it fine.